# Полиморфизм ли это?

Tags: терминология, полиморфизм

В книге Шмуллера по UML встретил кусочек текста в котором написано следующее:

> Иногда операция имеет одно и то же название в разных классах.
>   Например, можно открыть дверь, газету, подарок, банковский счет,
>   переговоры. В каждом случае выполняется новая операция, но каждый
>   класс "знает", как выполняется операция "открыть". Это и есть
>   **полиморфизм**.

Я привык к тому что слово `полиморфизм` означает, что одна и та же сущность имеет много форм. А то есть к примеру есть функция с одним и тем же именем но принимающая различное количество аргументов, ну или например класс который имеет разные конструкторы.

В случае же Шмуллера классы разные хотя имеют одноименные методы. Вот тут меня берет сомнение `полиморфизм` ли это?

Comment: То что вы раньше называли полиморфизмом - это перегрузка методов. "Выдранное" вами определение, на мой взгляд, по меньшей мере странное определение полиморфизма. А вот если все они унаследованы от одного класса и в них переопределена эта функция "открыть" - то это полиморфизм. И тогда базовый класс как раз и будет сущностью, которая имеет много форм - реализаций

Comment: Пример полиморфизма на php. Достаточно понятно расписано, весь код с комментариями. https://habrahabr.ru/post/37576/

Comment: @Trymount, я этого не придумывал, читал в книге, так вот выдержка из википедии: `В языках программирования и теории типов полиморфизмом называется способность функции обрабатывать данные разных типов` , так же я говорю о свободных функциях, ну и в довесок расшифровка слова полиморфизм (поли-много , морфе-форма).

Comment: @Trymount, кстати, перегрузка методов и функций это способ добиться полиморфизма.

Comment: перегрузка - переопределение - насколько я погуглил, разные вещи. 
Открыл вики. Два вида полиморфизма. Первый - параметрический. Представляет собой то, к чему вы привыкли.  ad hoc полиморфизм - то, к чему привык я, и то, про что пишет Шмуллер

Comment: @Trymount, а о переопределение я ни чего не говорил, это и так ясно что одно заменяют другим.

Comment: ну вот переопределение и является вторым типом полиморфизма, который описан в книге.

Comment: Полиморфизм - очень широкое понятие. Завастую имеется в виду способность работать одним способом с разными данными. Если вы хотите говорить про полиморфизм более конкретно, то нужно понимать, в контексте какого языка программирования, потому как полиморфизм как понятие в различных языках сводится к кокретным языковым фитчам. Как правило, речь идет о переопределении методов, иногда также имеют в виду их перегрузку.

Answer (score 0):

> В случае же Шмуллера классы разные хотя имеют одноименные методы.

Имеются ввиду разные классы, но у них что-то общее.

В простейшем случае - сущность, объект. Для них понятие "открыть" абстрактно, т.е неизвестно, что открывать.
От него и наследуются разные классы, где "открыть" приобретает конкретное действие. Например, для сущности "дверь" будет выполнено "открыть дверь", а для для сущности "папа за завтраком" - "открыть газету" и т.д.
То есть, действие станет известно когда сущность приобретёт конкретные черты.

Это и есть полиморфизм.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это полиморфизм. На техническом языке - метод с одинаковой сигнатурой в каждом унаследованном калссе имеет свою собственную реализацию.